# Banshee messes up album artwork when syncing with iPod

Tags: banshee, ipod

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.04 and used Banshee to sync my music from my iPod onto my computer. When I turned my iPod back on (it's jailbroken) the album artwork was messed up and placed to incorrect albums, but on Banshee the album artwork is placed to each correct album.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I have a feeling it's because your iPod is jailbroken. I plugged mine in and it didn't cause any issues even remotely close to that... I will certainly do a search for you though...

Answer (score 1):

It happened to mine as well, and it's not jailbroken. Here's a list of what I actually did
1. In iPod go to Settings>General>Reset>Erase All Content and Settings. Obviously this option will erase all your music, videos and apps in your iPod.
2. Wait for it to finish.
3. Sync your iPod again with Banshee. There shouldn't be any problem with the album art in iPod after that.

Take note that this method might not fix your album art problem 100%. While it did work, but at times, the album art might start go awry again. This is especially obvious if you have a large library.

Answer (score 0):

**If it is only a few albums in question** that have incorrect cover art, I might have a better solution for you. and it doesn't require erasing **all** your music--just the album or two that are jacked up. So delete the albums in question from your iPod **NOT YOUR HARD DRIVE**.

All right.

Granted Banshee is up and running, your iPod is plugged in, and Banshee recognizes your iPod--no disrespect just making sure.

- If you haven't already, click on **VIEW** on Banshee's top menu bar. After the drop down menu is open, click on **SHOW COVER ART**.
- Next, select the album with the incorrect cover art, and play a song from that album.
- When the incorrect cover art comes up in the lower left corner of
  Banshee, **RIGHT CLICK** on the cover art and select **DELETE THIS
  COVER ART**.
- Then **RIGHT CLICK** on Banshee's generic cover art and **CHOOSE NEW COVER ART**.
- Then select the correct cover art from your own catalog.
- After Banshee is done syncing the new cover art, you can drag the fixed album, or tracks to your iPod.
- At this point yoour problem should be solved.